# BLE: Relationship between MTU and maximum characteristic size?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do I find out the relationship between MTU and maximum characteristic size in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)?

I have a BLE developer board running an 'echo' program - so whatever it receives, it just immediately replies.

On my Android device, if I request an MTU of 247 bytes (which succeeds) and then write a 247-byte characteristic, it gets sent as two packets: one with 242 bytes and one with 5 bytes.  Any attempt to write a characteristic with more than 244 bytes results in 2 packets - the first one with 242 bytes, the second one with the remaining bytes.  Not sure why the first packet is 242 bytes long instead of 244, but there it is.

If, instead, I request a 100-byte MTU, the same kind of thing happens, but the packets get split when the characteristic is more than 97 bytes long, and the first packet is always 95 bytes long.

So it seems pretty clear that on this particular Android device, the maximum packet length is 3 bytes shorter than the MTU value. I've seen pages talking about MTU on the iOS where the packet length is 3 bytes shorter than the MTU value.

Am I guaranteed that the difference between MTU and maximum characteristic length will be 3 bytes, on all mobile devices and all BLE implementations?

Answer (score 14):

Almost. The ATT header consists of one byte opcode and two bytes for the ATT handle. If you use the "Write Long Characteristic Values" there is also a two byte offset parameter. If you use the "Signed Write Without Response" procedure (which nobody uses and almost no stacks support) there is also a 12 byte signature.

Also note that the maximum characteristic length is 512 bytes. The maximum allowed MTU is however 65535 bytes. You can never write a characteristic value larger than 512 bytes, no matter how large your MTU is.

If you're interested in the low level details of the ATT protocol you can read the Bluetooth Core specification at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification, Vol 3 Part F.

Comment: Nicely put Emil, just to add on: Overhead in the payloads is different for Write Characteristics(3 bytes) and Read Characteristics(1 bytes).